# In VBA, referencing an Excel worksheet using a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable called 'attached' that increments each time a certain condition is verified as true.  When that condition is true, I'm trying to select a worksheet that was created earlier that has the name "Attachment(x)". 'x' is a number 2,3,4, etc.  For instance, a worksheet might have the name "Attachment (3)".  In my code, x will be the value that the incrementing variable 'attached' has achieved at that point.

What code will select the worksheet based upon the current value of the variable 'attached'?  I declared the variable attached as a variant......Dim attached As Variant.

I just keep getting errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To select the sheet, do this:

```
Worksheets("Attachment(" & x & ")").Select
```

Comment: Beat me to it.  Although, it may be a typo in the OP, but I think his "Attachment" and "(" have a space between them for the worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your variable (named `Attachment(#)`) will decide which sheet to use (sheet named `Attachment (#)`)?

I assume you're using some kind of loop that iterates through the #, so you could do something like this

```
For i = 1 to 100
  myAttachment = "Attachment(" & i & ")"
  myWorksheet = Worksheets("Attachment (" & i & ")")
next i
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  I'm away from home this evening, but will try it when I return home.  You folks are a good resource.  Thanks so much.